# Execution order of html

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, iframe, web

I want to know HTML parser's parsing sequence.

Given two html files:

page1.html

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="x" src="page2.html"></iframe>
<div id="z"></div>
<--! something that need to be parsed -->
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="y">
<body>
</html>
```

I know iframe tag downloads src in parallel (i.e., HTML parser parses subsequent lines of iframe tag although iframe src (in the example, page2.html) is not yet downloaded).
So, the question is, **when the page2.html is parsed**?
In other words, when the div element (id=y) is added to DOM tree?
Is it done **after parsing codes** in page1.html or done **immediately after complete downloading of page2.html** by blockinig page1.html parsing? Or, do HTML parser parses page1.html and page2.html in parallel (at the same time)?

Any comments and links would be appreciated.
Thanks!

(If there are wrong questions, please let me know. Actually, I am new to JavaScript and HTML)

Comment: Just curious, why do you care?

Comment: Assume that there is a function in page1.html that accesses objects defined in page2.html. The function can access undefined things depends on parsing order

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage .

Comment: Is it worth to read the article to know the answer? The article for what? Please briefly mention about that.

Comment: Basically it gives you a way to setup listeners on events, versus trying to guess what loads first.

Answer (score 0):

Exact timing depends on the browser. `page1` should be downloaded and ready first, before `page2` is ready. However, `page1` is not ready prior to the start of downloading and parsing `page2`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your second sentence appears to depend on unstated assumptions about the relative size of `page1` and `page2`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual order things are done in is browser dependent, but in a typical browser, it first builds a tree of the HTML in the page you are visiting and then processes it. When it gets to processing the iframe, it will then go and request that page.

Now, this is complicated by the fact that the HTML is downloaded in chunks from the server, so from the partial tree, it might start downloading the content from the iframe before it's even seen half of page 1.

The take-away though is that you shouldn't be relying on this behaviour.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly? what is the answer of my question :)?

Comment: @freddy your question is explained in the answer: you can't be sure. Don't rely on the behaviour. If you need to know, there are eventListeners you can add.